# Properties of the "distinguished logarithm"

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, exponential-function

It's been a long time since I was working in complex analysis. I remember that we can (uniquely?) extend the exponential function to a continuous function $\mathbb C\to\mathbb R$, while the natural logarithm can only be extended to $\mathbb C$ in the sense of a multivalued function.

While I don't want to dive to deep into this topic, there is one particular result I need to work with and which I'm currently using in a black-box fashion: If $\varphi\in C^0(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb C\setminus\{0\})$ with $\varphi(0)=1$, there is a unique $\psi\in C^0(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb C)$ with $\psi(0)=0$ and $\varphi=e^\psi$ and, **abusing notation**, we **define** $\ln\varphi=\psi$ (which is not to be confused with the composition of a function called "$\ln$" with $\varphi$). $\ln\varphi$ is called the *distinguished logarithm* of $\varphi$.

> On the one hand, the notation introduced above seems plausible, since $\psi$ is uniquely determined by $\varphi$. On the other hand, I wonder whether this notation is compatible with the "usual properties" of the logarithm on $\mathbb R$ which we are used to work with. For example,
>
> 1. if $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$ are two instances of $\varphi$, can we verify that $\ln(\varphi_1\varphi_2)=\ln(\varphi_1)+\ln(\varphi_2)$?
> 2. if $d=1$ and $\varphi(x)=e^{{\rm i}x}$, can we verify that $\ln\varphi(x)={\rm i}x$?

In (2.), if I remember correctly, the "usual" multivalued logarithm $\log$ on $\mathbb C$, would yield a set $\log(e^{{\rm i}x}$. Does the distinguished logarithm somehow select the single element ${\rm i}x$ of this set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you state holds because $\mathbb{R}^d$ is simply connected.  And (1) and (2) are both true, because you can verify in each case that the right hand side satisfies the properties of the distinguished logarithm on the left hand side, which is uniquely determined by those properties.

Nevertheless, this notation has a potentially confusing issue which you have already pointed out, namely:

> $\ln \varphi$ is not to be confused with the composition of a function called "ln" with $\varphi$.

So there is no function $\ln$, only a function $\ln \varphi$. This means that in (2), when you write $\ln \varphi(x) = ix$, the left side must be read as $(\ln \varphi)(x)$ and not as $\ln (\varphi(x))$.  If you read it as the latter, then from $\ln(\varphi(x)) = ix$, you would get an apparent contradiction by substituting $x=0$ and then $x = 2 \pi$, since $\varphi(0) = \varphi(2 \pi)$ but $0 \ne 2 \pi i $.

For your last question, the distinguished logarithm does select $ix$ in (2), but it is not as magical as it might initially seem. From the definition of the distinguished logarithm, it is a function $\psi(x)$ satisfying $e^{\psi(x)} = \varphi(x) = e^{ix}$.  Of course $\psi(x) = ix$ satisfies that.